# How to set the current node count in AKS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-resource-manager, azure-aks

I am using Azure AKS, version 1.18. And using the following snippet of ARM

```
 "agentPoolProfiles": [
                    {
                        "name": "agentpool",
                        "osDiskSizeGB": blah,
                        "count": 5,
                        "vmSize": blah,
                        "osType": blah,
                        "maxPods": 28,
                        "maxCount": 5,
                        "minCount": 1,
                        "enableAutoScaling": true,
                        "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks",
                        "vnetSubnetID": blah,
                        "type": "VirtualMachineScaleSets",
                        "mode": "System"
                    }
                ]
```

But the above doesn't increase the current node count in the AKS. I would like to have a minimum node count of 5 and then scale the nodes from there onwards.

[image]

Here' the related documentation however, its not explaining where/how the current node count plays

[Azure AKS reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/scale-cluster)

Answer (score 0):

Your config has created a nodepool with initially 5 nodes (`"count":5`), and enabling the cluster autoscaler to automatically down-scale that nodepool to 1 (`minCount:1`) and up-scale to 5 (`maxCount:5`).  It looks like the autoscaler has downscaled the inital 5 nodes down to 3 because your workload resources only needs 3 nodes.

If you want a start with 5 as a minimum, and scale from there, use the following (assuming a upper limit of 20 nodes):

```
"count": 5,
"minCount": 5,
"maxCount": 20,
```

Comment: this is not changing the current node count to 5

Comment: @sbolla How do you change the current node count and the minimum count? Create an AKS cluster or just change the existing cluster?

Comment: To scale the current node count to 5 nodes you can run "az aks scale -g <resource_group> -n <aks_name> -c 5",  but because you are using the autoscaler, the autoscaler may scale the cluster back down to 3.